# wp_postmeta - lot of meta fields

Tags: mysql

I found a lot of meta_key + meta_value fields in my database in wp_postmeta. They are all same only meta_id and post_is changign. And there is more than thousands of them. Look at the pic.
[image]

Should I somehow delete them? Because they could slow down my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not Core entries so far as I know. That means that a plugin or a theme has inserted them. Since I don't know which plugin or theme it is, or whether you are still using that plugin/theme, I can't say whether you should delete the entries. If you are still using the plugin or theme you would probably break something.

Whether or not this will slow down your site also depends on the plugin or theme that created the entries and on *how* those fields are used, in particular on how they are retrieved. I general you can have thousands and thousands of entries and not notice a performance hit, but there *are* some uses that would severely impede MySQL performance. I don't know if any of those apply.

Finally, this is a guess but what that looks like to me is a poorly considered mechanism for providing default values for certain keys. There are better ways to provide default in formation that pre-populating the database like that... *but that is a guess*. Without know the knowing the details I can't be sure.

You are going to have to try to find what is inserting those fields. If you have shell access to the server, and it is a *nix server (Linux, BSD, or Unix proper), use [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) and look for those keys. Hopefully they are hard-coded. `id_field` looks distinct-ish (`filter` will get hundreds of results) so `cd` to `wp-content/plugins` and try -- `grep -Rni --exclude="*.css" --exclude="*.js" "id_field" ./`

Comment: Here is my all plugins which I am using: http://pastebin.com/Ca0irkwh and I am using theme: Jarida.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I can't read through _39_ plugins to sort this out for you. You are going to have to do that grunt work for yourself.

Comment: I didn't even expect from you to do that :D. Could you just tell me how to investigate all pluigns one by once? What exactly should I search in source code?

Comment: @usrbowe : see the edit

Comment: cool thanks. Unfortunately I haven't direct access to my server (shared webhosting). But I can search for this keyword offline in my local backup copy.

Comment: Offline is perfect... better than trying to search the production server.